# how can I change the eyes and add other textures like eyebrows to this model

Tags: modeling, texturing

I use a Blender page called Build_A_Bod to make my
male and female models as they have a zillion shape keys but I cant figure out how to add eyes and other textures to these models , anyone have any suggestions ? also warning these models are not appropriate for work or children.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=12V-yuW0wzp1i4-q8kD833KoW_wttyoHU

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hd8cFDRltZWk8V_FsqKmBnjJfaOh6_dU

Comment: You could try adding a procedural skin texture to the model. However, the best way here would be to UV unwrap the model. Then you add a blank texture and texture paint your skin in Texture paint mode. Substance Painter is really good for baking textures. With eyelashes, again you can paint them or add a strip of vertices, UV unwrap it and add a transparent texture with an alpha for hairs. You can create seperate UV Maps for parts of the body in the "Data Tab", scroll down to UV Maps and press the plus button. In Edit Mode, Mark Edge Seams, Select what part you want to unwrap and press "U".

Comment: Was something like this what you were looking for? I'm unsure because for me this is a very general question if you don't mind me saying. However, I've packed a procedural skin texture into one of your files which you can append to your other files and play with plus a HDRI environment lighting texture. I'm not an expert at procedural skin textures but I was reasonably satisfed with the results of this one I set up. Here's my dropbox link to the file. Let me know if it works :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jefyhb18d97bh5/Build_a_Female_Procedural_Skin.blend?dl=0

Comment: thank you much  appreciate the time and work you spent on the node workup will try to figure this out but may be slow as I am very novice at blender only 6 weeks now

Comment: Yes it’s a bit much to take it all in at first but one bite at a time. I started 3D in April last year. The human characters you have there are very well made and use UDIMs which are all the rage. Unfortunately, blender doesn’t support UDIMs at the moment, although there is a developer who has made quite a bit of progress in that area. Perhaps we’ll see it in blender soon. UV unwrapping, is something you’ll need to know about that sooner or later. There are many videos on youtube which would explain it better than I could through text lol. All the best

Comment: Mr Jackson would you be interested in a business proposition?

Comment: Perhaps! However it will probably be better to communicate in private. My e-mail is: 
spira3d@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Select your model
Enter Edit mode. Switch to vertex mode
Select eye left using CTRL+Right click: Select 1 middle point of the eye. Click on Ctrl+"+ numpad" to grow eye selection. Then switch to front view. Press "U". Select project from view.

You now have a separate UV from the body. Create a new material (yes in edit mode) and assign it to those vertices. From there on, create an eye texture by assigning a white blank texture, switch to texture paint interaction mode (1) and paint. Save image in the UV editor.
[image]

The rest of the body has UVs already. Click on object properties from the properties window on the VERTEX tab (triangle shape of icons)
Like this: https://streamable.com/l2di8

Thank you for your consideration in voting my answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Keep adding materials assigning them into a shader on the list you have for materials.